# Updating angular directive with service

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

my aim is to pull parts of the menu structure from the backend and "inject" it into my menu. This depends on the state of the app (logged in/out and user rights).

I build a directive:

```
AppDirectives.directive("menutagebuch", ['MenuStructureService',function(MenuStructureService){
    /// get the html from the backend
    var getelement  = MenuStructureService.get();
    var elementtoinsert = angular.element(getelement);

    return {
        restrict: "A",
        template: elementtoinsert,
        link: function(scope,element){
            // some $scope.$watch to recall MenuStructureService.get(); on $rootscope change
        }
    }

}]);
```

My Service:

```
AppFactories.factory("MenuStructureService", function($http) {
  return {
    get: function() {
      var getMenuStructure = $http.get('/menustructure').success(function(data){
        return data;
      });
    }
  }
});
```

The problem I have is that the directive executes before the menustructure is loaded... what do I have to do differently or am I using a wrong approach? Very new to angularJS.

Comment: imo you should call the directive from the factory, not call the factory from the directive. Or better still use a controller to mediate that communication.

Comment: are you returning html from `'/menustructure'` ? If so why aren't you just using `templateUrl` in directive? Code has a number of problems so not exactly sure what overall goal is

Comment: Ye I'm getting the html with '/menustructure' from the backend, so ye kinda a template, but I just want to 'inject' the html into the menustructure. The menu contains different dropdowns. Depending on the user and state those change. The backend just serves the appropriate html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok the way I solved it is to move all the "actions" into the MenuCtrl and to watch the auth status. If the auth status changes it calls the factory MenuStructureService to get the elements for the menu. With ng-show and ng-repeat I then control the action of the menu being shown/hidden and the elements being filled.

Auth status changes:

```
$rootScope.authstatus = true;
```

The controller handles the actions:

```
$rootScope.$watch('authstatus',function(){
        MenuStructureService.get();

      });

$rootScope.$on('menustructure', function(event){
        $scope.menu = $rootScope.menustructure;
});
```

MenuStructureService:

```
AppFactories.factory("MenuStructureService", function($rootScope, $http) {
  return {
    get: function() {
      $http.get('/menustructure').success(function(data){ 
        $rootScope.menustructure = data;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('menustructure', 'updated');
        return data;
      });

    }
  }
});
```

The backend serves the elements depending on the current authstatus.

Answer (score 1):

Yes the question is if you actually want to use a directive here.
Or is a controller enough for you.
If you do want to write a directive for this and you want to manipulate DOM elements you should do that during the compile step.

To do it Angular style use a template for your diretive rather then doing jQuery style DOM manipulation in the compile step.
If you use a template you could then access your service in the link step.

```
//Service
...
get: function() {
  // Rather than handling the success in the service return the promise directly
  return $http.get('/menustructure');
}
...

//Directive
...
link: function(scope, element) {
  scope.menu = MenuStrucutureService.get();
}
templateUrl: "...template.html"
```

...

```
<!-- Example Directive Template -->
<div ng-repeat="item in menu.admin.items">
  <span>{{item.name}}</span>
</div>
```

A directive controller probably does not make sense here, if you follow the rule of thumb from the angular docs:
"Best Practice: use controller when you want to expose an API to other directives. Otherwise use link.".